# What is meant by “global RNA polymerase occupancy”?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology

I read the following in a paper

> It provides base-pair resolution and strand-specific information of **[global RNA polymerase** occupancy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5502525/).
> CDK13 cooperates with CDK12 to control **global RNA polymerase II** processivity

What does this mean?

Comment: Please provide a reference to the article/textbook you are citing.

Comment: "Global" tends to be used in contrast to "local". I think you need to read the paper to find out more specifically.

Comment: it looks like you are posting quotes without acknowledging them as as such or noting where they come from. It would help for you to clearly restate a more expansive version of your question outside of the title for us to be able to help more effectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In context of the PRO-seq method, "global" can be substituted for "genome-wide". Note that use of the term *global* is a call-back to the methodological predecessor of PRO-seq, which was called [**global run-on sequencing**](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2833333/) (GRO-seq).